# How to use Outlined material icons in an angularDart project?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, google-material-icons

How can I use material icon outlined theme in an angularDart project.

```
<material-list *deferredContent>
            <div class="mat-drawer-spacer"></div>
            <div>
                <material-list-item>
                    <material-icon icon="inbox"></material-icon>
                </material-list-item>
                <material-list-item>
                    <material-icon icon="star"></material-icon>
                </material-list-item>
                <material-list-item>
                    <material-icon icon="send"></material-icon>
                </material-list-item>
                <material-list-item>
                    <material-icon icon="drafts"></material-icon>
                </material-list-item>
            </div>
        </material-list>
```

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by outlined theme?

Comment: https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=outline

Answer (score 1):

Currently the icon font, which we leverage, does not provide the outline icons. So it is currently not supported until they start exposing them.